# Be there or be square

Tags: riddle, word

- When it is just me I have 3
- Yet when there are more, I have four
- My first two are double
- My last two can clarify
- Leave my middle one alone, though, and soon you'll be talking to yourself
- You'll know you have me when all of me points right back to you

*What am I?*

---

Hint:

> Watch out! Snakes can be deadly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This time I'm sure, you're

> a **die**

*When it is just me I have 3

Yet when there are more, I have four*

> **Die** is pluralized as **dice**

*My first two are double*

> The prefix **di-** means double indeed (e.g. dioxygen $O_2$)

*My last two can clarify*

> **ie** is an abbreviation for **id est** which is Latin for "That is"

*Leave my middle one alone, though, and soon you'll be talking to yourself*

> **I**, it's still me!

*You'll know you have me when all of me points right back to you*

> The sum of all pips on a die is equal to 21, which correspond to the letter U in the alphabet. That can be interpreted as "you". (Thanks @Stiv !)

*Hint*

> A famous dice combination in [craps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps) is **Snake Eyes**, which is the worst one you can get (pair of 1s), and that might have caused some people (fictional or real) to meet an unfortunate end.

Comment: Always felt like I was so close to solving it, and now I think that's finally it! (if not I'll definitely leave my spot for someone else)

Comment: Yep, you got it! Ill reward you the answer when you're able to solve that last line. Ill give you a hint, if you choose to take it: rot13(tvira gung gurer ner znal inevngvbaf, gur ynfg yvar pna or fbyirq jura ersrerapvat gur gvgyr, juvpu pbhyq uryc gb pynevsl *nyy bs gur qvr*)

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 V qvq guvax vg jnf nobhg gur qvr orvat phor-funcrq, ohg V whfg pbhyqa'g svaq rabhtu whfgvsvpngvba sbe "zr" abg orvat gurer

Comment: rot13(Xabjvat vgf n phor vf gur svefg fgrc. Abj pbafvqre jung vg pbhyq zrna gb unir nyy bs gung phor-funcrq qvr) **THE NEXT LINE MAY OR MAY NOT REVEAL MORE THAN YOU WANT** rot13(Jura lbh hfr n qvr, jung nobhg vg vf pbzzbayl hfrq jvgu rnpu ebyy?)

Comment: Oh, fdhner snprf, did not think of this

Comment: I mean yes, but that's pretty much directly related to your previous statement. At this point i think you should rot13(guvax yrff nobhg gur culfvpny nfcrpg bs gur phor, naq zber nobhg ubj vgf hfrq). I'll admit the solution to this last one is definitely tricky, and certainly not very straightforward, though I think youre making good progress. I'm sure if I were to reveal specifically what you should do next, you could figure it out quite easily.

Comment: The last line *might* be an obscure A1Z26-related way of saying that rot13(gur fhz bs nyy cvcf ba n qvr vf gjragl-bar - gur gjragl-svefg yrggre bs gur nycunorg vf 'H', juvpu fbhaqf yvxr 'lbh') - but I'm not 100% certain if that's the intention...

Comment: That could make sense with "all of me"...

Answer (score 3):

*OLD ANSWER, READ THE OTHER ONE*
Are you perhaps

> a **bit**

*When it is just me I have 3*

> **Bit** has three letters.

*Yet when there are more, I have four*

> Its plural is **bits** or can even be **byte** if there are eight.

*My first two are double*

> The prefix **bi-** means "twice" or "two".

*My last two can clarify*

> **IT** is Information Technology, the study of using computers for research, or send and transmit information.

*Leave my middle one alone, though, and soon you'll be talking to yourself*

> **I**, that's me!

*You'll know you have me when all of me points right back to you*

> Not sure about this one either, but there are bits everywhere on the device I'm using.

Comment: Re 'Leave my middle one alone' - you've done the opposite here! Keep the other one instead and you'll see the significance of the line...

Comment: Oh I was thinking leaving it alone as in removing it from the whole, but that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: That solution works well! Unfortunately, it's not the one I was going for. Once solved, the last line will make more sense. Great job though!